# Installing DESEq2 Error: unable to access index for repository https://bioconductor.org

Tags: r, installation, package, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I have recently updated my macOS, R and R studio. The new versions are as follows:

> MacOS: macOS Big Sur, version 11.6

> R: 4.1.1 (2021-08-10) -- "Kick Things"

> R Studio: 2021.09.0 Build 351 "Ghost Orchid" Release 077589bc, 2021-09-20) for macOS)

I regularly use the package `DESEQ2` available from Bioconductor:
[Differential gene expression analysis based on the negative binomial distribution](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/DESeq2.html). However, after the update, when I run the commands (for R version 4.1) to re-install `DESEQ2`:

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("DESeq2")
```

I now get the following error during installation (multiple lines stating this):

> Warning: unable to access index for repository https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.13/bioc/src/contrib:
> cannot open URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.13/bioc/src/contrib/PACKAGES'

`DESEQ2` will not load because of it. Also, when I navigated to the link in the error - its an error: [Page Not Found](https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.13/bioc/src/contrib:%20%20%20cannot%20open%20URL%20%27https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.13/bioc/src/contrib/PACKAGES%27/)

For context, I have been able to download other packages via the `BiocManager::install()` without issue after the updates.

Does anyone know how I can by-pass this to install `DESEq2`?

Comment: I am curious if Bioconductor is doing some kinds of updates. When I click on the link you posted, I actually get "Access Forbidden"  rather than "Page not found"

Comment: Interesting. I clicked on the link again and it worked, but not the install. Perhaps it is undergoing some update or maintenance or wonky stuff. I will try to download again tomorrow. Thanks for the suggestion. I think you may be right.

Comment: It actually was strange. When you brought up this question. I tried downloading DESeq2 on two of my device that have the same settings. I used the same commands as you, one device had an issue downloading the package, while the second one, which I started downloading maybe 30 minutes later didn't have an issue downloading DESeq2

Comment: Neuron: Ok - I have figured this out this weekend. From my end, I had a firewall activated in the background on my computer that was not allowing access to the `Bioconductor` index repository `DESEQ2` needed for download. Once I turned that off, I was able to download `DESEQ2` without issue. Thank you very much for your attempts to help me. It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out this error from my end: I had a firewall activated that was running in the background of my computer that was not allowing access to the `Bioconductor` index repository `DESEQ2` needed for download. Once I turned that off, I was able to download `DESEQ2` without issue.

Comment: Very interesting. I will keep that in mind in the future. Thanks for circling back to answer your question